# Bootstrapping databases after CloudFormation creation

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation, circleci, amazon-ecs

(#1) So I've got an RDS (postgres) db created via a CloudFormation stack. I have the root db ("postgres") created and the master username/password. Now I need to actually hand off to the application itself.

(#2) The application deployment process is responsible for:

- Ensuring it's database exists
- Ensuring it's users/roles exist (eg. "service_user", "read_only" "read_write").

(#3) The application itself (actually a migration agent) is responsible for:

- Ensuring the table structure exists
- Any init data required etc.

Now I've got the CloudFormation part (#1) and got the application part (#3) working pretty nicely. I have a problem with (#2), we use CircleCI and unfortunately that leaves the deployment itself running outside our VPC.

So does anyone have any suggestions for running essentially a 1-time script, inside an AWS VPC, for bootstrapping database users?

I'm thinking a lambda function initially, but seems a little painful. Ideally if there is a way to tack it on the end of the CloudFormation stack that'd be fantastic! I just don't want to run it from the application itself as that'd require the application having the master username/password which I'd like to avoid.

Thanks,
Alex

PS. We use ECS so ideally trying to avoid using EC2 UserData features too (which seems like the recommended solution in all the AWS docs for now :/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a snapshot from RDS and then specify to start the RDS from the snapshot.  You would need to create the snapshot and mark it to not delete when you delete the RDS instance.

Comment: Yeah that's certainly a viable option but requires manual work to set up the snapshot (or automating that process). Trying to work out what AWS recommends for this problem, seems like it should be fairly common.